# Rails replace if/elseif block by guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create a table of cash transactions inside of PDF using Prawn gem. To do so I iterate through the Hash with `parsed_cash_transactions` but before each is started I need to save the `last_item` of that Hash to check when I should display the summary table below the main table.

```
  def transactions_row
    last_item = parsed_cash_transactions.last[:position]

    parsed_cash_transactions.each do |cash_transaction|
      # some operations with cash_transaction item
      table_end_position = cursor

      if last_item == cash_transaction[:position] && table_end_position < 204
        new_page
        draw_gray_line if cash_transaction[:position].to_i.even?
      elsif table_end_position < 15
        new_page
        draw_gray_line if cash_transaction[:position].to_i.even?
      end
    end
  end
```

To deal with all requirements I've got `if block` below. I'm wondering is there a better, cleaner way to replace that `if block`? maybe I could use guard somehow?

```
      if last_item == cash_transaction[:position] && table_end_position < 204
        new_page
        draw_gray_line if cash_transaction[:position].to_i.even?
      elsif table_end_position < 15
        new_page
        draw_gray_line if cash_transaction[:position].to_i.even?
      end
```

Comment: A _guard clause_ is put right at the beginning. It would return from the block early and therefore not execute the main part. But from your code, it seems as if you want to execute the `if` part _after_ the main part. I don't think a guard clause is the right tool here.

Comment: Yup you're right, but don't you think current if block is a little messy?

Comment: What's the _purpose_ of that `if` block? Why do you have `last_item` along with `table_end_position < 204` and then a separate `table_end_position < 15`? Some context would help to suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indeed use a guard clause, although it is not the most pretty, since it condition is pretty long.

```
  def transactions_row
    last_item = parsed_cash_transactions.last[:position]

    parsed_cash_transactions.each do |cash_transaction|
      # some operations with cash_transaction item
      table_end_position = cursor

      next unless last_item == cash_transaction[:position] && table_end_position < 204 ||
                  table_end_position < 15

      new_page
      draw_gray_line if cash_transaction[:position].to_i.even?
    end
  end
```